# iOS Reusable components

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

During my work with development of iOS applications, i noticed that almost every application has some parts that are repeated. For example every application has user management logic, Login, Sign Up, Forgot password. 
And every time, i find my self trying to manually import already developed logic (View controllers, nibs, storyboards).
My question is how can i implement these common features in separate component, so i can simply reuse them every time i start new project. Also notice that there should be possibility for small customisations, for example all apps have login screen, but UI design varies for every app.

Long story short, what i need is:

1. How to encapsulate commonly repeated features in separate component.
2. How to inject the component in the newly started project.
3. How to make customizations at the component, without changing the component core.

I guess that here should be made some combination of Framework (Or static library) and cocoa pods, but i wanted to hear if somebody have already developed some concept about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***How to encapsulate commonly repeated features in separate component.***

Whatever you choose you are going to have to factor out the code your separate component requires from your code base. This is the first step in the entire process - so think long and hard about if it makes sense to turn it into a separate component.

*So now you have some code you would like to reuse...*

There are a number of ways of doing this, such as [Xcode's workspaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html), stand alone source files, static libraries and frameworks. Cocoa pods is a package manager and will help you maintain your framework - not write it :(

**[Xcode's workspaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html)**

> A workspace is an Xcode document that groups projects and other
>   documents so you can work on them together. A workspace can contain
>   any number of Xcode projects, plus any other files you want to
>   include. In addition to organizing all the files in each Xcode
>   project, a workspace provides implicit and explicit relationships
>   among the included projects and their targets.

**[Static Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html)**

> Introduction to Using Static Libraries in iOS
>
> Static libraries provide a convenient mechanism for sharing code among
>   multiple applications. On iOS, static libraries are the only supported
>   library type. This document explains how to extract code from your
>   application into a new static library and how to use that static
>   library in multiple applications.

**[Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002253-99920-BAJFEJFI)**

> In OS X, shared resources are packaged using standard frameworks and
>   umbrella frameworks. Both types of framework feature the same basic
>   structure and can contain resources such as a shared library, nib
>   files, image files, strings files, information property lists,
>   documentation, header files, and so on. Umbrella frameworks add minor
>   refinements to the standard framework structure, such as the ability
>   to encompass other frameworks.
>
> Frameworks are packaged in a bundle structure. The framework bundle
>   directory ends with the .framework extension, and unlike most other
>   bundle types, a framework bundle is presented to the user as a
>   directory and not as a file. This openness makes it easy for
>   developers to browse any header files and documentation included with
>   the framework.

**Source Files**

These are the classes you have factored out of your code base. You could just include them in each project you use them - for instance a separate repo, that contains all of your shared/common code that you add to your Xcode project's workspace. Very simple, not the best to maintain.

***How to inject the component in the newly started project.***

Depending on how you choose to implement your common code will effect this step. For source files you just need add them to the project and set the target. For frameworks or static libraries you will have to [embed them in your project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_a_Framework.html)

For workspaces you will add the projects containing the shared code to the main projects workspace.

***How to make customizations at the component, without changing the component core.***

Again you may find yourself refactoring code so that you expose the UI controls or logic functions that you want to be able to customize. As a general rule the more you expose the more complex the code gets.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, exactly as you supposed, the way I opted for to reuse components is through a static library or sometimes a framework of reusable components, implementing common logic or well structured classes to inherit from in the new projects, which I make available to the new projects as a CocoaPods development pod sitting on my development machine or in a shared git repository. This way should answer your questions 1 and 2. For your question 3, you can either opt to perform customisations to the core dismissing pod updates, or to adapt the core methods to a possible override in the destination project. Hope it helps.

Comment: For the 3rd question, you may play with IBInspectable properties, then configure components in each projects through storyboard (considering it's viewable component).

Comment: for the 3rd point I would go with delegation (see UICollectionView, UITableView etc) which is widely used in Cocoa Touch